# Git: How to merge upstream changes without causing a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have (commits were created in alphabetical order)

```
origin/topic  A-B-C-D-W-X

topic         A-B-C-D-Y-Z
```

Is there a way i can get my `topic` branch to look like

```
A-B-C-D-W-X-Y-Z
```

**without** introducing a merge commit?

---

Ordinarily I'd just do

```
$ git checkout topic
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge --ff-only origin/topic
```

But since `Y` and `Z` were committed after `W` and `X`, a fast forward will not work.

I suspect some clever rebasing or cherry picking might work but I can't wrap my
head around it :{

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try with:

```
git checkout topic
git pull --rebase origin topic
```

Check the [fetch man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) notes about the rebase option.

I would recommend using something like [git-smart](https://github.com/geelen/git-smart), which will do a fast forward (which is faster) when possible, and if not, then a rebase. It will also stash local changes if you have any and give you a summary of the remote changes that were pulled.

Comment: This is simply incredible... now to spend time actually understanding how it's working...

Comment: @naomik remember, you can think of Git as just a tree of commits with post-it notes (representing references and branches) attached to them.  You're simply copying/moving commits around and re-applying the post-it notes when you rebase.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to [mamapitufo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223182/456814), you can also do the following, which will give you the exact same result:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/topic topic
```

The last `topic` parameter is optional if you already have it checked out.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have `topic` checked out and `origin/topic` fetched which is tracking origin/topic (sounds like you do), you could just:

```
git rebase
```

I gave mamapitufo an up vote.